# undefined method `countries_collection' for CountryStateSelect:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am using the country_state_select gem on simple_form,though my authentication is done using devise,i get this error each time i try to load
 the page with the country_select option

"undefined method `countries_collection' for CountryStateSelect:Module"

my code is below

```
f.input :country, collection: CountryStateSelect.countries_collection
```

but it never loads,i keep getting that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
gem 'country_state_select', '3.0.0'
```

in your `Gemfile`.

I got the same error you did, so I tried the latest version and it works. `bundle` failed because of a conflict, though, so I had to `bundle update` and then it worked.

Comment: but i now have another problem,i only get states in US in my state select field,even after adding js inline @jason.

Comment: yeah you just need to use the latest version from rubygems.